# Split column code - to repeat using "each()" jQuery

Tags: jquery, each

The following code will:

- split columns by dividing the number of elements in half then it will
  -create a new div and add the remaining content to the new div

Below I am trying to do this using "**each()"** and it -mostly- works except it is adding the *new div* ***.second*** the the first instance of  ***#container*** -although it IS reading each group and splitting correctly.

jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('body > #container').each(function(){
var select = $(this);
//var chooseme= select.find('#container');
var count= select.find('div.firstcol > div.datarow').length;

if (count>1)
   {
        if (count & 1)
        {
        $("<div></div>").attr('class','secondcol').appendTo('#container'); 
        $('div.firstcol > div.datarow').eq(count/2).nextAll().appendTo('.secondcol');
        } 
        else
        {
        $("<div></div>").attr('class','secondcol').appendTo('#container'); 
        $('div.firstcol > div.datarow').eq(count/2-1).nextAll().appendTo('.secondcol');
        }
    } //if

 });//each

  });//ready
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<style>
body{font-family:arial;}
.firstcol{float:left;padding-left:100px;background-color:#ccc}
.secondcol{float:left;color:blue;position:relative;padding-left:100px;}
.secondcol h3 {font-size:18px;font-weight:normal;color:grey}
span{}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="firstcol">

<div class="datarow">
<span class="label">File Type</span>
<span class="value">JPG File</span>
</div>

<div class="datarow">
<span class="label">File Type</span>
<span class="value">JPG File</span>
</div>

<div class="datarow">
<span class="label">File Type</span>
<span class="value">JPG File</span>
</div>



</div>
</div>
<!--**********second group****************-->


<div id="container">
<div class="firstcol">

<div class="datarow">
<span class="label">File Type</span>
<span class="value">JPG File</span>
</div>




<div class="datarow">
<span class="label">File Type</span>
<span class="value">JPG File</span>
</div>



</div>
</div>
```

After: as the code renders this will result:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="firstcol">
<div class="datarow">
</div>
<div class="secondcol">
**<div class="secondcol">**
</div>
<div id="container">
<div class="firstcol">
<div class="datarow">
<div class="datarow">
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is I want that **secondcol** to go into the **second container**

Comment: Is that HTML what you're starting with, or what you want to end up with? Could you post both the *before* and the *after*?

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to understand your description, can you reword it? or include a jsfiddle? Also, doesn't `$('body > #container')` just select `#container`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cdcWf/ I attached the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't give two HTML nodes the same ID. IDs are supposed to be unique! :) Try changing the ID to the second instance of the `container` to something else, update this in your javascript as well (`appendTo('#container2')`) and see what happens

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would work, but I am working on a site that spawns multiple instances of the same divs. So, hard coding unique id's won't help. should I sub ID's with classes?

Comment: it is **integral** that you name each element with a unique id. You can either do this using the `.attr("id","newid")` method to name your other spawned instances in jQuery. Or you can give the containers a common class in order to select them all. Using this method you can then select all containers `$('.containerclass')` and cycle through each element, or using index to get a specific instance `$('.containerclass')[0]`.

Comment: I'm new to creating new id's and indexe any suggested threads?

Comment: You just have to make sure that elements have a unique id. So, when you spawn a container, change the id if your copying something that already had an id. When your writting your html make sure u folloe the same rules. If you want to group elements, then give them the same class and select them using `$('.classname')`. Hope this helps. If not initoate google!

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely running into problems because you're using the ID `#container` more than once.

Change your `<div>`s to `<div class="container">`, and then update the selector for your `each` function:

```
$('div.container').each(function() {
  var select = $(this);
  // your code
  .appendTo(select);
});
```